# UIImageView's contentmode not respected when setting image during runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I've got a `UIImageView` which is displayed fullscreen as a 'background'. Whenever I set a image in the `viewdidload` as it's default, it the `contentMode` works just fine.

However, when I do this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.pickedPhotoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; // set desired contentMode here
    self.pickedPhotoImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.pickedPhoto = image;
    [self.pickedPhotoImageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

All respect for the `contentMode` is lost and when taking a photo only a tiny bit of the photo is shown. How can a UIImageView lose respect of a property just like that?

Comment: Try setting the content mode after setting the new image.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either.. I'm setting it in the viewdidload as well. Is it common to set the contentMode after every time you set a new photo?

Comment: Do you have constraints set up on the UIImageView? I'm wondering if the imageView is growing due to a larger image being set. One way you could check is use the "Debug View Hierarchy" in Xcode 6 once the image is set.

Comment: Sweet, that was it! Thanks @ryanwils. If you answer my question I'll mark it as correct. Could you maybe explain in the answer why it resizes when a large picture is added even tough i've clipped it to bounds and set the contentMode?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I've added my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the `UIImageView` has constraints set up properly. With Auto Layout, the size of each view is determined by the view's `intrinsicContentSize` [(link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize). This means when you reset the content of a subclass of `UIView`  (wether it's the text in a `UILabel` or in this case, the image in `UIImageView`, auto layout will calculate the new size. If you don't have the proper constraints set up and set a content size larger than the current frame size, the frame will grow.

As to why this is happening even though you are setting the `contentMode` and `clipsToBounds`, `contentMode` seems to be done after the fact and will work with the constraints of height and width (either the height and width you give it, or the calculated height and width from the relative constraints on X and Y). `clipsToBounds` works in the same way, where it will clip anything outside of the frame's bounds after the layout has been calculated. In this case, the layout was calculated and deemed to be larger than the screen, and set the frame of the `UIImageView` accordingly which is why you only saw a tiny bit of the photo.

Hopefully that explanation helps!

Comment: I spent way too much time before stumbling into this answer. So thank you very much. For anyone else facing issues like these, it usually happens when you have outlets inside a storyboard and are then making changes via code while also downloading images from a server.